# List box's macro: Adding index formula to Linked Cell

Tags: excel, listbox, excel-2010, vba

I have created a list box (xactive control) with macro shown below:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    With Sheet1.ListBox1
       .AddItem "AAA"
       .AddItem "BBB"
       .AddItem "CCC"
       .LinkedCell = "$A$5"
    End With

End Sub
```

To complete the list box, when click "AAA" shows 1, click "BBB" shows 2 and click "CCC" shows 3.

I have searched for two days online that the solution is to add index formula to Linked Cell. However I can not use the index formula since my List Fill Range is in macro.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NECESSARY CHANGES**

In the VB Editor, double click Sheet1 and enter the following code:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()

    Sheet1.Range("$A$5").Value = ListBox1.ListIndex

End Sub
```

Remove this line from your code:

```
.LinkedCell = "$A$5"
```

and run it again. Now select an item from your listbox.

**OPTIONAL SUGGESTION**

Just a suggestion, you could use this for your existing code. Little bit more succinct, especially if you have to add more items.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim data() As Variant
    data = Array("AAA", "BBB", "CCC")
    Sheet1.ListBox1.List = data
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Tested both method.

Comment: First method is working fine but there are glitch to other linked formula. I assume it's take more time to process. For the second method after adding the macro, the list repeat itself. Other that than it's remain the same. Can you review the second method?

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by first and second method? Do you mean the two different Workbook_Open routines?

Comment: Base on my understand, method 1 is Private Sub ListBox1_Change() and method 2 is Private Sub Workbook_Open().

Comment: The second method doesn't work like first method. But it's great to replace my old macro. If you don't mind, it is possible for method 2 to work like method 1.

Comment: Ah, you need both pieces of code I've supplied here. `Sub ListBox1_Change()` is required to have your listbox update the relevant cell. The `Workbook_Open` routine I've provided was just a suggestion for changing your existing code to make it a little more readable and maintainable; but your existing code will work fine as well, as long as you remove the `.LinkedCell = "$A$5"` line as I suggested.

Comment: I've edited the answer to hopefully make it a little more clear.

Comment: Good to know that you are helping a lot. More than thanks. Thanks. Have a good day.